# How to boot in download mode with a Zonda a450

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

Already googled this, no results, i tried with youtube video tutorial in which you supposedly boot your phone in download mode while holding the volumen down button and the power button, but it doesn't nothing.

I have a Zonda a450 with android 4.4, i want to boot in download to upgrade to android 5.

Comment: What are the specifications fot this device?

Comment: @esQmo The site is from argentina so it's in spanish http://zondatelecom.com/detalle-ZA450.html the specs are at very end of the web page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey. As described in the specs, the device has a Spreadtrum chipset (SC7731). There is no boot mode on SPD devices.

To flash a ROM, you need a file in the `.pac` format and use a flasher (ResearchDownload).

You MUST install SPD drivers, otherwise the device won't be detected by the computer.

As there is no download mode, just swicth off and plug the device by holding volume down or up.

Comment: i found a .pac file for itel it1408 which uses the same chipset, but no idea if this gonna be a good idea, i not sure if they are compatible

Comment: Don't flash ROM intended for another device, even though they have similarities!

Comment: i couldn't find an apropiate .pac file for my phone =/, any other methods to do this?

Comment: Nope. it's the only method. Ask for support on the manufacturer website.